# Displaying Data from different tables in View

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor, model-view-controller

Just wanted to ask if there's something I missed here.
I have two tables that I joined together in my controller
using .NET MVC btw
anyway, here's my controller:

```
namespace Review.Controllers
{
    public class ReviewController : Controller
    {
        ReviewContext db = new ReviewContext();
        ReviewItemsContext db2 = new ReviewItemsContext();
        MainDataModel db3 = new MainDataModel();

        List<UAR_Review> uar_review = new List<UAR_Review>();
        List<UAR_ReviewItems> uar_reviewitems = new List<UAR_ReviewItems>();


        public ActionResult Index(int? page) {

            ViewBag.AccList = (from r in db2.UAR_ReviewItems
                               select r.Account).Distinct();

            /*var entities = from s in db2.UAR_ReviewItems
                            orderby s.Account
                            select s;*/

            var entities = from s in uar_review
                           join st in uar_reviewitems on s.ID equals st.ReviewID into st2
                           from st in st2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select new MainDataModel { UAR_Review = s, UAR_ReviewItems = st };


            int pageSize = 15;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(entities.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my view:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Review.Models.MainDataModel>
@using PagedList.Mvc;

<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Review", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <h2>Index</h2>

    @section NavBar{

        <h3>Period: 2 of 2018</h3>

        @Html.DropDownList("userAccount", new SelectList(ViewBag.AccList), "Select Account to Filter")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />    
        }

    @section MiddleSection{

        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <span class="arrow-link contrast-large light-blue">@Html.DisplayName("Name")</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <span class="arrow-link contrast-large light-blue">@Html.DisplayName("Role")</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <span class="arrow-link contrast-large light-blue">@Html.DisplayName("Action")</span>

                </th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                <tr>
                    <td>
                       <span class="font-gotham-narrow">@item.UAR_Review.DisplayName</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <span class="font-gotham-narrow">@item.UAR_ReviewItems.Role</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.UAR_ReviewItems.Response)
                        <span class="font-gotham-narrow">
                            @Html.RadioButton("Response", "Retain")@Html.Label("Retain")&emsp;
                        </span>
                        <span class="font-gotham-narrow">
                            @Html.RadioButton("Response", "Remove")@Html.Label("Remove")
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <br />
        Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
            new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I run it there is nothing being displayed in the Site.[here's the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFcYT.png)

I just wanted to ask if there's anything I missed.
Also, please disregard the dropdownlist on the left side, I've been planning to use it to sort the shown elements in the page by AccountType(This is stored in my UAR_ReviewItems table). For now, I'm just trying to figure out what's wrong here and why there are no elements being displayed.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in your code before you return entities to check if there is data in there?

Comment: You are not setting uar_review & uar_reviewitems from database data.

Comment: @Saadi what do you mean? UAR_Review and UAR_ReviewItems already has content inside my SQL Database.

Comment: @mahlatse i did, when I tried to check the content of "entities" in the immediate window, this is what it says: {System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__23<<>f__AnonymousType6<Review.Models.UAR_Review, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Review.Models.UAR_ReviewItems>>, Review.Models.UAR_ReviewItems, Review.Models.MainDataModel>}
    Results View: Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable

Comment: Try expanding the results and see if you get any data

Comment: @mahlatse how do I do that? Terribly sorry, just started to learn 2 weeks ago and haven't figured out everything yet.

Comment: @mahlatse i tried typing Entities.ToList() in the immediate windows, I got a "Count = 0" on it

Comment: Expand the results and check if there are any values, or try doing a .count() to see if the figure is a positive number

Answer (score 0):

Your screen grab does say the PageCount is 0.
Your Model in empty. Check your queries.